# Change react version

Tags: php, html, reactjs

I'm new to using react. I already make react project, then I check the react version of my project. It's 17.0, and I want to make hooks project, so I run the command npm install --save react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0, and after that I check the version again and it's already 16.8.0 .  But when I start the npm, I see an error that reads "Fast Refresh requires React 16.10 or higher. You are using React 16.8.0.". Should I create a new project with version 16.8.0 or how do I fix this error? I was searching around and couldn't find out how to create a new project with the version of react that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use.

```
npm i react react-dom
```

That should get you the latest version of each

Comment: I try that, the version change to 16.14, I want 16.8 because there is hooks feature

Comment: @Nadia — They didn’t take hooks out again between .8 and .14!  Nor did they take it out for version 17.